# Updating progress bar using grails

Tags: java, ajax, file, sockets, grails

We have a web application developed using Grails in which client communicates with the server through socket. At the same time a file gets written in local drive by a java process which needs to be read and displayed in web page along with a Progress bar that moves every step when the client sends the message "PROCEED" through socket. If the client sends the message "STOP", socket must be closed and File reading must be stopped along with the progress bar reaching to 100%.

I have made some research and found [this](http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/)

But the problem is, I don't know how to get the value for progress bar and the file which is in my controller class into my ajax javascript to use it to move the progress bar and to display the file.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to see what you tried?

Comment: On googling I think this can be achieved through AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with my last project but unable to solve due to time constraint and then I opt for jqueryUI progressbar , it might be helpful to you
here is how is used it :

```
$("#divID").progressbar({value: false}).hide();
$("#submitBtn").click(function() {
 progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
     progressbarValue = progressbar.find( ".ui-progressbar-value" ); 
 progressbarValue.css({
          "background": '#B80000'
        });
 $.blockUI();
$("#divID").show();
});
```